# Rotating file handler gives error in python log

Tags: python, logging

below file rotation config works fine when you have enough file size set. However, if file size is less for one run of program, then it gives error while file rotation. I fear this can happen even when my log file is full and needs a new creation. Can anyone tell me how to handle this error, which happens only in new log file creation(i.e. rotation)

`--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 70, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 171, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 111, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\gitLab\\python-scripts\\log_proj\\project.log' -> 'C:\\gitLab\\python-scripts\\log_proj\\project.log.1'
Call stack:
  File "C:/gitLab/python-scripts/log_proj/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/gitLab/python-scripts/log_proj/main.py", line 10, in main
    logger.info("Program is over")
Message: 'Program is over'
Arguments: ()
2021-07-05 14:35:52,153 - [INFO] - __main__ - (main.py).main(10) - Program is over

Process finished with exit code 0`


    
`import logging
from logging import handlers

_log_format = f"%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s]-(%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"

def get_file_handler():
    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('project.log', maxBytes=10400000, backupCount=2)  # max log file size 100 MB
    #file_handler = logging.FileHandler("project.log")
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    return file_handler

def get_stream_handler():
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    return stream_handler

def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(get_file_handler())
    logger.addHandler(get_stream_handler())
    return logger`



`import package1
import app_logger

logger = app_logger.get_logger(__name__)

def main():
    logger.info("Program starts")
    package1.fun()
    logger.warning("This should appear in both console and log file")
    logger.info("Program is over")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`

Comment: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Are you running the script multiple times in parallel? Are you opening the log file in some other program while or before the script runs? This is probably not a python problem.

Comment: no i am not running program multiple time. I just make sure that say if all my statments takes 100 bytes to log, i kee log file less than 100 bytes just to test in rollover case it should not create any issue. but here it what happens.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see my post in main thread, it is not occuring there. But if you, observer the crash stack, you will find that it stuck while creating a new file for rotation ie   project.log --> project.log.1   not sure why? it should create new file without any error if the existing log file gets filled

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue for RotatingFileHandler under Windows. Please use [concurrent-log-handler](https://pypi.org/project/concurrent-log-handler/) instead. Sample snippet below:

```
from concurrent_log_handler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler

def get_file_handler():
    file_handler = ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler('project.log', maxBytes=10400000, backupCount=2)  # max log file size 100 MB
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    return file_handler
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).